# The sum of a product of two random variables: how do I know if each summand is independent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

So I have a question that involves using SLLN and almost sure convergence:

- I'm given $Y_{1},Y_{2},Y_{3}\ldots$ as iid r.v.'s with a finite mean $k$.
- I'm also given this sum
  $$
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}Y_{i+1}\
  \overset{\rm a.s.}{\rightarrow}\ k^{2}
  $$
  and asked if the SLLN applies here.

My question is:

- Is there a  surefire way to tell if each summand $\left(~Y_{1}Y_{2},Y_{2}Y_{3}, \mbox{etc.}~\right)$ is iid with finite mean $?$.
- What would be the case for a different sum, say,  $$
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}Y_{2i - 01}\ Y_{2i}\ ?
  $$

Comment: Are you happy with a proof that there are counterexamples for which they are not independent, or you want a general proof that they can never be independent (unless they are constant)? (My current answer shows the latter)

Comment: What you sent was perfect!  Intuitively, I guessed that the overlap would cause dependence but I wasn't too sure.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I edited my answer to add a full characterization of *when* those things would be independent, in case that's useful. It's quite limited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the summands are **not i.i.d.** in general (rather, they are identically distributed, but **not** independent). An easy way to see it is to consider the following: letting $Z_i := Y_i Y_{i+1}$ for every $i$, you have
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z_i Z_{i+1}]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_{i+1}\cdot Y_{i+1}Y_{i+2}]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_{i+1}^2Y_{i+2}]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_i] \mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1}^2]\mathbb{E}[Y_{i+2}]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_1]^2\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2]
$$
(using independence for the second-to-last equality, and the i.d. assumption for the last).
On the other hand,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z_i]\mathbb{E}[Z_{i+1}]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_i Y_{i+1}]\mathbb{E}[Y_{i+1}Y_{i+2}]
= \mathbb{E}[Y_1]^4
$$
so if the expectation is non-zero$^{\dagger}$ the two differ unless $\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2]=\mathbb{E}[Y_1]^2$, i.e., unless $\mathrm{Var}[Y_1]=0$ (that is, unless $Y_1$ is constant a.s.).

For the second case where the summands are $Y_{2i} Y_{2i+1}$, however, you *would* have independence as the indices of different summands do not overlap.

---

$(\dagger$) Overall, one can prove the following result (based on this, and the comment below for the case $\mathbb{E}[Y_1]=0$, in which case you apply the same argument to $\mathbb{E}[Z_i^2Z_{i+1}^2]$ and conclude that $|Y_1|$ is constant a.s.):

> **Theorem.** Let $(Y_n)_{1\leq n\leq \infty}$ be a sequence of real-valued i.i.d. random variables, and set $Z_n := Y_{n}Y_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then, the $Z_n$'s are not pairwise independent unless either
>
> 1. $Y_1$ is constant a.s.; or
> 2. $Y_1$ is uniformly distributed on $\{-a,a\}$ for some $a>0$.
>
> Conversely, in both cases (1) and (2) the $Z_n$'s are mutually independent.

Comment: Note that if $k=0$, then the argument doesn't allow you to conclude they are dependent. However, you can then apply the same thing to $\mathbb{E}[Z_i^2 Z_{i+1}^2]$ and end up concluding that if the summands are independent, then one must have $Y_1^2$ is constant a.s., which since we have now assumed $\mathbb{E}[Y_1]=$  means that $Y_1$ is uniform on $\{-1,1\}$ for some $a$. That shows that the only non-constant case for which those increment could be independent is when $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ are scaled Rademacher.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Clement C, SLLN does not apply directly. However, you can apply it indirectly as follows: whenever $n$ is even,
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_iY_{i+1}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{n/2}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}Y_{2i-1}Y_{2i}+\frac1{n/2}\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}Y_{2i}Y_{2i+1}\right)
$$
Also as mentioned by Clement C, the variables $Y_{2i-1}Y_{2i}$ are iid, so you can apply SLLN two show that the first sum converges to $E[Y_1Y_2]=k^2$, and same for the second. Therefore, the whole sum converges to $\frac12\left(k^2+k^2\right)=k^2$.

(This technically only proves the limit as $n\to\infty$ through the even integers, but you can deal with odd $n$ with a little more work).